# Resources for modularizing C applications

Tags: c, gcc, makefile, configure

I am looking for some resources that speak about managing large C projects using make, header files, building configure files etc.

What resources are used by the community? Any good ones for beginners?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here the list for your particular question

- [C Interfaces and Implementations: Techniques for Creating Reusable Software](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201498413)
- [Managing Projects with GNU Make](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596006101)
- [Actively participate in a notable open source project or three](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/06/the-ultimate-code-kata.html)

Instead of make can start with cmake or scons.

Comment: For Unix-like environments, if you're going to rely on third-party libraries and want to be portable, `make` won't suffice; an understanding of GNU autotools and/or CMake will be required.

Comment: well in this case my list should be extended to http://www.amazon.com/Autotools-Practioners-Autoconf-Automake-Libtool/dp/1593272065 but unfortunately I didn't get chance to read it and fall in love with cmake :-)

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest that if you're able, learn about an alternative to make such as [Scons](http://www.scons.org/documentation.php). It's good for small and large projects alike, and it's Just Python(tm) so it doesn't have the horrible mangly "syntax" of makefiles.

That aside, for general project layout, you may want to read [this GameDev article](http://www.gamedev.net/page/resources/_/reference/programming/languages/c-and-c/organizing-code-files-in-c-and-c-r1798).